# Ошибка при использовании диффернциальной эволюции в SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

Я объявил функцию, я хочу найти ее минимум методом диффернциальной эволюции.

```
import math
def f(x):
    return math.sin(x/5.0)*math.exp(x/10.0)+5*math.exp(-x/2.0)
from scipy import optimize
bounds = [1, 30]
result = optimize.differential_evolution(f, bounds)
```

Но после запуска скрипта я получаю такую ошибку:

```
# population is scaled to between [0, 1].
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

`bounds` - это не просто пара (min, max), а список из таких пар. Исправление на `bounds = [(1, 30)]` должно всё исправить.

[Описание и пример в официальной документации](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что границы значений аргументов функции представляют собой список кортежей (list, в который помещены объекты типа tuple). Даже если у вас функция одного аргумента, возьмите границы его значений в квадратные скобки, чтобы передавать в этом параметре список из одного кортежа, т.к. в реализации scipy.optimize.differential_evolution длина этого списка используется чтобы определить количество аргументов функции